# ForgeViewer v7 - broken API. How to get list of viewables

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I have been using this method to extract the list of viewables from the loaded document (as recommended by API documentation).

```
 geometryItems = Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(adocument.getRootItem(), {
     'type' : 'geometry',
     'role' : '3d'
 }, true);
```

In v7, getSubItemsWithProperties() function is not available. It is not mentioned in the release notes or API document page either.

Could someone explain how to replace my code with new API?

Thanks,
Bandu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v7, the `Document.getSubItemsWithProperties` method has been deprecated in favor of `BubbleNode.search`.

For more details on migrating from v6 to v7, please refer to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/.